# App language (Locale) automatically gets reset to default after opening camera to capture a photo or gallery to select image

Tags: java, android

We have a setLocale function as following:

```
 public static void setLocale(Context context, String locale) {
            Locale myLocale = new Locale(locale);
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        }
```

We use above method as follows:

```
sessionManager.setAppLanguage(locale, this);
setLocale(context,sessionManager.getAppLanguage(this));
```

We are using following locales:

```
English = "en";
        Hindi = "hi";
        Marathi = "ma";
```

But everytime when we open a camera, capture a photo, some labels get reset to default language and some labels remain in selected language.
This happens in case of selecting photo from gallery also.

Note: Issue is device specific. Now we are seeing in Samsung star pro (KITKAT 4.1) and Sony Xperia E3 dual (KITKAT 4.4.4)

Comment: which lang you want to set to  after capturing the photo

Comment: Where are you calling the `setLocale` method?

Comment: We ask user to select language at first time when he logs into the app. We save this in shared preferences and set selected language for further use.
We want to keep this language throughout the app till user does logout.

Answer (score 2):

It might happen that you are calling the `setLocale` method in your `Activity` initialization, such as in `onCreate` method. You might want to call it in `onActivityResult` also.

Comment: We ask user to select language at first time when he logs into the app. We save this in shared preferences and set selected language for further use.
We want to keep this language throughout the app till user does logout.